# Is BooleanRegion limited to only the most trivial cases?

Tags: regions, computational-geometry, boolean-computation

Consider these four regions:

```
regions = Disk[#, 1] & /@ Tuples[{0, 4/5}, {2}]

Graphics[{FaceForm[Opacity[0.2]], EdgeForm[Black], regions}]
```

[image]

I was looking to get subregions which are part of some of these and not part of others.  [`BooleanRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanRegion.html) should be able to do this.

For example,

```
BooleanRegion[And, BoundaryDiscretizeRegion /@ regions]
```

[image]

But any non-trivial combination (i.e. anything else than using the simple operators `And`, `Or`, etc.) seems to fail when more than two regions are present.

For example, try

```
BooleanRegion[#1 && #2 && ! #3 && ! #4 &, BoundaryDiscretizeRegion /@ regions]
```

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

I was very surprised to see this because if these cases don't work, then `BooleanRegion` seems to be pointless. We might as well just use *a single* `RegionUnion`, `RegionIntersection`, etc. Also, the computation I'm after *can* be expressed in terms of *several* region unions, intersections and differences. Thus what I'm expecting from `BooleanRegion` does not seem to be difficult to implement.

Comment: The problem seems to exist only for `MeshRegions` and `BoundaryMeshRegions`. For example, `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@
 BooleanRegion[#1 && #2 && ! #3 && ! #4 &, regions]` works as expected...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher You're right!  I was so convinced that it is much easier to compute with discretized regions that I didn't even try descretizing only afterwards.

Comment: Moreover, I think that the problem with discretized regions is `BooleanRegion[Not, region]` because that cannot be represented by a discrete region. Maybe one needs to replace `Not` somehow by the `RegionComplement` with respect to a common `BoundingRegion`... Maybe it is also possible to modify the boolean function with `BooleanConvert`...