# BooleanRegion with .stl files does not work

Tags: regions, mesh, boolean-computation

Im trying to use `BooleanRegion[]` on an .stl file.
The imported .stl file is called *pores* and is of type `MeshRegion` (`MeshRegionQ[] and RegionQ[] give both True`).

Here is also a snippet of ?pores:
`pores = MeshRegion[{{6141.84, 3115.36,9443.80},...,{5617.29,3599.17,8546.06}}, {Polygon[{{1,2,3}, ..., {5253,6518,2148}}]}]`

*pores* represent pores of a material, that was scanned. What I'm trying to do is subtracting these *pores* from a `box=BoundingRegion[pores]`, which yields the rest of the material. When I try doing this with

```
BooleanRegion[#1 && ! #2 &, {box, pores}]
```

it gives me the input back unevaluated. Same happens when I try using `RegionDifferece[]`. I tested all possible combinations. However what is working as expected is

```
BooleanRegion[#1 ∨ #2 &, {box, pores}]
```

There is also an example in the Help of `BooleanRegion[]` and `RegionDifference[]` especially for MeshRegions, that exactly fits my case and works fine as long as is dont plug in the *.stl* Data (*pores*). 
Therefore i had a look at the Data itself and figured out that the `MeshRegion` of the pores uses polygons and `RegionBound[]` uses Tetrahedrons. So I thought there might be a problem, because the *pores* are represented by surfaces. Thus I tested the following with 1 pore only

```
pore=Delaunay[MeshCoordinates[pore]]
BooleanRegion[#1 && ! #2 &, {box, pore}]
```

The `Delaunay[MeshCoordinates[pore]]` gives you tetrahedron elements as well, but the results are not evaluated as before.

It seems that im not the only one encountered that problem: [Is BooleanRegion limited to only the most trivial cases?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173294/is-booleanregion-limited-to-only-the-most-trivial-cases) Here a similar problem occured, but the author was able to use BooleanRegion for non-discretized regions and discretize everything afterwards. As far as i know i cant make a undiscretized region out of a MeshRegion, can I? Is there a way to make `BooleanRegion[]` work?

Comment: Hi N.Schl and welcome! Thanks for taking the [tour] . It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). [Edit](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) if improvable. In this case it would help to have a **minimal working example of code and data** for us to run. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Answer (score 2):

I can provide this alternate workflow. Let's suppose your imported mesh is `R` below.

```
R = DiscretizeRegion@Sphere[];
```

Now we create a bounding box `B` and create a `BoundaryMeshRegion` `S` containing the boundary of the pore(s) and of the box.

```
B = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cuboid[#1 1.1, #2 1.1] & @@ BoundingRegion[R]];
S = BoundaryMeshRegion[
   Join[MeshCoordinates[B], MeshCoordinates[R]],
   Polygon[Join[
     Join @@ MeshCells[B, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[All, 1]],
     Join @@ MeshCells[R, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[All, 1]] + MeshCellCount[B, 0]
     ]
    ],
   PlotTheme -> "Wireframe"
   ]
```

[image]

In order to obtain a tet mesh, you can discretize `S`.

```
 DiscretizeRegion[S, PlotTheme -> "Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that idea. I have tried it.  It works if there is only 1 pore. If i do it with more than 1 pore though i get a solid without holes.  Furthermore one of the pores is exactly on the boundary, so i get the following error: BoundaryMeshRegion::binsect: The boundary curves self-intersect or cross each other in BoundaryMeshRegion

Comment: Try the newly edited version. It adds 10 percent of spacing to the bounding region.

Comment: i already did something similar for testing. The thing is i cant enlarge the region, because i want to use this as specimen (RVE=representative volume element) for a finite element simulation. If i have extra space between the pores and the boundaries to make BoundaryMeshRegion[] work, it might change the response in the simulation.

Comment: I would rather bother about pores touching the boundary box in FEM as this would lead to obtuse tets.

Comment: As long as proper boundary conditions are given why should that be a problem?

Comment: Because obtuse tets deteriorate the accuracy of FEM significanty.